# git-svn revert locally committed delete

Tags: ubuntu, git-svn

git-svn is currently driving me mad.

I ran:

```
git rm <file>
git commit
```

The file is still in the svn repo, but I have no idea how to check it back out so that it is in revision control.  I want to do the equivalent in svn to:

```
rm <file>
svn update
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've not pushed the commit out to the Subversion repository using `git svn dcommit`, you can back out a single Git commit using `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

Answer (score 1):

With `git commit` you commit removal locally. You should run `git svn dcommit` then, it's an analog of `git push`.